# Changing the Value of text on dynamic TextInput

Tags: javascript, expo, react-native, textinput

I am trying to add simple textInput using javscript and expo Everything is working such good except when trying to change the value of text is giving me an error

I did try a lot of things but nothing works

```js
const AccountsAddScreen = props => {

  const [inputList, setInputList] = useState([{accountName : ""}]);



const handleInputChange = (e, index) => {
  const list = [...inputList]
 const {accountName, value } = e.target
list[index][accountName] = value;
setInputList(list);
};


const handleRemoveClick = index => {
  const list = [...inputList];
  list.splice(index, 1);
  setInputList(list);
}

const handleAddClick = () => {
  setInputList([...inputList, {accountName : ''}]);
}


console.log(single)

  return (
    <View style = {styles.container}>
      <Text>
       We are Testing 
      </Text>
      <View>
        {
          inputList.map((x, i) => {
            return (
              <View key = {i}>
              <TextInput 
              placeholder = 'Add Account Name'
              style = {styles.input}
              value = {x.accountName}
              onChangeText = {e => handleInputChange(e, i)}
              />
            {
              inputList.length !== 1 && <Button title = 'Remove' onPress = {()=> { handleRemoveClick(i)}}/>
            }
            {
              inputList.length - 1 === i && <Button title = 'Add' onPress = {handleAddClick} />
            }
              </View>
            );
          })
        }
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  input : {
    borderColor : 'black',
    borderWidth : 1
  }
});

export default AccountsAddScreen;
```

and the error I am getting is

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_e$target.accountName')

Answer (score 0):

```js
const {accountName, value } = e.target
list[index][accountName] = value;
```

should be

```js
const { value } = e.target
list[index].accountName = value;
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to do like below.

```
  const handleInputChange = (e, index) => {
    const list = [...inputList];

    list[index]['accountName'] = e;
    setInputList(list);
  };
```

'e' hold the value of the updated text, you can simply set it to the one in the index that you pass in i.